# Most efficient way to store and save a large number of Keras models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently trying to solve a multi-class classification problem using multiple binary classification models (~100 classes). Each model comes out to around 70-100MB, and in order to test, I need to load every single model. It takes about 2-5 seconds per model, so loading all the models takes a long time.

Is there a way to either save each binary classification model as one giant model, and have it predict each class separately, or is there a way to load multiple models at the same time?

I tried using load_model() with multiprocessing, but I quickly ran into an OOM error (I only have 4gb of VRAM), even if I had 3 processes running concurrently.

The architecture for each model is identical.

Comment: Why not have a single model that predicts all the classes?

Comment: My accuracy drops dramatically because I don't have enough data for the model to learn to predict multiple classes. Doing one model per class yields the best loss/accuracy.

Comment: You could augment the data to increase the dataset size. Training 100 models for this is incredibly inefficient and difficult to make predictions on.

Comment: But I have very good accuracy and loss...? I already augment the data and it still yields poor results.