# How to stack Keras models horizontally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Is it possible to do something like this in Keras? :[image]

Except Model A,B,C are all stacked horizontally into one model? I've seen some solutions that utilize an input layer, but whenever I use an input layer, I seem to get an error when I try to load a model.
Is there a way to load all the models, concatenate them, and save as a single, new, larger model?

EDIT: I already have all the models trained. I want to combine them after the fact.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve ensemble learning or? I did not understand to purpose of having seperate outputs for every model.

Comment: I think you can do that by `layers.concatenate`. However not sure about it, but you can try.

Comment: @Frightera I'm doing a multi-label classification problem as a series of binary classification networks. Before you ask: Yes this is 100% the way I want to solve my problem. I want to combine the models into one large model so that I can load a single model, rather than wait for each model to be loaded when I test.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my idea, let's assume you have these models to stack:

```
model_1 = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = model_1.input, outputs = model_1_out)

model_2 = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = model_2.input, outputs = model_2_out)

model_3 = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = model_3.input, outputs = model_3_out)
```

If you want to stack the models, not concatenating their outputs:

```
models = [model_3 , model_2 , model_1]
stacked_model_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(x, x, x))
model_outputs = [model(stacked_model_input) for model in models]
stacked_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=stacked_model_input, outputs=model_outputs)
```

**model_outputs** gives: (Passed 3 for here.)

```
[<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 3) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'model_2')>,
 <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 3) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'model_1')>,
 <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 3) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'model')>]
```

Produces:
[image]

For to save stacked model:

```
from tf.keras.models import save_model
save_model(stacked_model , 'model.h5')
```

I am not sure how you can use their seperate outputs but, that's how you can stack them.

**Edit**: You can use their outputs by defining seperate loss etc. Or since they are stacked and input is shared, you can get each model's outputs to create a new mode with its weights. I don't know if you can cut them from the stacked model, so that's why I said getting each output.

Comment: Hmm. Would it be possible to do something like this, but with weights? Since each of my models have the same architecture, it would be inefficient to save the full model each time. I'm starting to think that even if I combine it, I'll run out of VRAM.

Comment: Stacked model is a new model, so I don't think that there is a more efficient way to do this since models are trained.

Comment: I have a side question which may solve this problem indirectly. I've tried solving this problem using multilabel classification, and both the validation and training loss go below 0.01, with accuracy roughly 99%, yet when I test it myself (using model.predict), I get very poor results. This is the reason why I'm trying to combine multiple models, because each performed well.

Comment: You can average each of their outputs, and get a prediction on them maybe?

Comment: For the multilabel or separate binary?

Comment: What are the models originally trained on? I suggest that you can combine each of the outputs then you can average to have a prediction. Kinda like ensemble learning but averaging the outputs to get a prediction.

Comment: My [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955655/most-efficient-way-to-store-and-save-a-large-number-of-keras-models) better explains the problem I'm trying to solve. How would averaging the outputs of a multilabel model when I need to know all of the classes it predicts help me? If you're talking about each binary model, how would averaging all of my binary models help me either? I'm trying to take one input and get 'x' outputs, each of which is a probability of that class existing in the input, but in the most efficient way.

Comment: If each model performed well, by averaging all outputs should yield better results. I see that you are trying to zip the models somehow I think. When you stacked them there will be only one input and one output if you average their outputs.

Comment: I need separate outputs in order to predict each class.

Comment: Then I don't know an efficient way to do that, having 1 model is better IMO.

Comment: I'm not sure I made my problem clear. I have 100 classes (not mutually exclusive) I'm trying to predict from a given input. I have two ways of solving this: 1) I make a single model that outputs an array of 100 probabilities (multilabel classification) or; 2) I make 100 *separate* models, each outputting a *single* probability. 1st method has good accuracy but I have a lot of models, 2nd method has poor real-world performance, but it is a single model. I'm trying to find a way to combine the best of both.

Comment: It is more clear in my mind now. Predicting 100 classes is hard, but also having 100 seperate models would be very inefficient. I would try to go for multiclass classification model. Or as I did you can stack them, but it would be memory inefficient, but if you ignore that you can get every different output from them by specifying stacked model's outputs. Because getting 100 outputs from a network won't be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible in `keras`, but it would require some advanced knowledge of the API. In particular, you need to think about how you want to compute the loss of each output with respect to the input.

I'd suggest to check out the [developer guides](https://keras.io/guides/), perhaps starting with the [functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) and [custom training loops](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/).

Below is a sketch of how you'd create this type of network with the functional API.

```py
from tensorflow import keras

input_shape: int = 100
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(input_shape,))

units: int = 64
dense1 = layers.Dense(units)
dense2 = layers.Dense(units)
dense3 = layers.Dense(units)

out1 = dense1(inputs)
out2 = dense2(inputs)
out3 = dense3(inputs)
```

Comment: I already have all the models trained, I just need to combine them. Sorry for being unclear, I'll edit the original question.